Conditional line break only if no "natural" break would occur
I have a rather long text inside an intrinsically sized div. For visual reasons I'd like the div to break at a given point but only when no "natural" line break would occur "before" this point:

I could achieve this by adding a <br>, placing the text into multiple divs etc. but I found no way to ignore this break, when the div shrinks below the point where it would naturally break "before" that preferred break point:

Is there any technique to achieve this with pure CSS & HTML?
Example code
Here's an example with the "static" line break via <br> which shows the line break at the correct position when the div is very wide but does not work as required when the div shrinks (second screenshot above):


.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non orci in nunc venenatis luctus et eget mauris.<br>Pellentesque nec ante dignissim, malesuada tortor ac, rhoncus ante.
  </div>
</div>



Codepen Playground
Additional note
I'm specifically looking for a solution which does not require any fixed sizing like max-width div, media queries etc. b/c they would all be bound to the used font, font-size, browser zoom level etc. and could break e.g. when the user overrides the font(size) in his browser settings etc.
More examples
I'm adding more examples showing what I want & what I don't want because there seems to be some confusion about my actual requirement.
In this example, I replaced the "." at the point, where I'd like to add the break, with a "," because I hope this makes my intention a bit more clear.

Current conclusion
I think that what I want is technically not possible with vanilla HTML & CSS at the moment and I have not heard of any upcoming proposal yet which would provide the needed tech.
I'll probably stick to adding a fixed max-width which is a bit hacky but should work in most cases.

Please provide some code.

The <wbr> HTML element represents a word break opportunity—a position within text where the browser may optionally break a line, though its line-breaking rules would not otherwise create a break at that location.

@Paulie_D Replacing the <br> in the example code above with a <wbr> does not show any line break at all at the required position, regardless of the divs width.

I am pretty sure what you want, can't be solved with currently available CSS. Not if it has to be "dynamic."

I think there is some confusion about what you require. Could you add a picture showing what is required if the first part of the text goes over more than two lines?

@AHaworth I just added another picture showing what I want & what I don't want.

Thanks, that makes it clearer. I think we've concluded there is no way to do this with pure CSS/HTML. You would have to run some JS which tests whether there are some 'natural' line breaks or not.

I don't get it. If the <br> is removed the text wraps as it should.  I don't see under any circumstances in which that <br> being anywhere in this particular layout (or any layout with long lines of text), would be aesthetically appealing.

I'm afraid, the closest thing to get with CSS-only would be to replace the <br> line-break with a span element enclosing the desired dynamically breaking text content.


.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Inter;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* prefer one-line layout */
.dynamicLine {
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-wide {
  font-size: 1.25vw;
}

/* prevent single line for very wide width */
@media (min-width:90ch) {
  .dynamicLine {
    display: block
  }
}
<h3>Resize me</h3>
<div class="resize">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non orci in nunc venenatis luctus et eget mauris. <span class="dynamicLine">Pellentesque nec ante dignissim, <span style="color:red; font-weight:700; font-style:italic;">malesuada</span> tortor ac, rhoncus ante.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Prevent single line</h3>
<div class="content content-wide">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non orci in nunc venenatis luctus et eget mauris. <span class="dynamicLine">Pellentesque nec ante dignissim, <span style="color:red; font-weight:700; font-style:italic;">malesuada</span> tortor ac, rhoncus ante.</span>
</div>



How it works

the last "line" is wrapped in a <span> element
with display:inline-block applied to it
therefore, this "pseudo-paragraph" is drawn to the previous line – provided there is enough space
otherwise, this element is rendered starting on a new line

If you can't easily wrap your content you need some JavaScript to analyze line-wrapping results (e.g by comparing element heights)
To prevent a single line layout, you may add a media query specifying the breakpoint width by ch units like so
/* prevent single line for very wide width */
@media (min-width:90ch) {
  .dynamicLine {
    display: block
  }
}

This approach is slightly more flexible than using em or pixels as the ch unit is based on the zero digit's width – so we get a breakpoint at approximately >90 character. However, you still need an idea what would be a suitable breakpoint.

This is the closest to my requirements what I've seem so far but it doesn't wrap at all if the div is very wide & everything fits into one line which is a must have requirement for me. Maybe see the example image I just added with my latest edit to the question.

You may combine it with a media query using ch units. See updated example. That's the closest thing you can achieve with CSS-only

You could use a regular <br> tag and hide it, when the viewport size gets smaller.


.conditional-br {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 60em) {
  display: none;
}
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non orci in nunc veneatis luctus et eget mauris.<br class="conditional-br">
Pellentesque nec ante dignissim, malesuada torror ac, rhoncus ante.
</p>



Maybe you have to try out for yourself which breakpoint fits best.

I don't want to rely on fixed sizes. See the just added "Additional note" in my original question.

Something like this?


.parent {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
  word-break: break-word;  /* Ensures long words break if needed */
  overflow-wrap: anywhere; /* Allows breaking opportunities */
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non orci in nunc venenatis luctus et eget mauris.&#8203;Pellentesque nec ante dignissim, malesuada tortor ac, rhoncus ante.
  </div>
</div>




This doesn't break at all, when the div is very wide. Also it shows no space anymore between mauris. and Pellentesque. Am I missing something?
